# Exit an Access VBA Macro with an exit code returned to the shell / Scheduled Task Manager?

Tags: ms-access, vba, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2003

I'm running a [scheduled task](https://serverfault.com/questions/659430/what-event-id-is-generated-when-a-scheduled-task-fails-in-windows-server-2003/659436?noredirect=1#comment803271_659436) in Windows Server 2003.  When the scheduled task runs, it calls a VBA Macro which runs, does some database stuff, then exits.

The VBA Macro needs to return a non-zero value to the Shell / Scheduled Task Manager if something goes wrong in the Macro (for instance a database goes down).

Is it possible to return a non-zero value from the vba macro to notify the Scheduled Task Manager that something has gone wrong?  I'd like to be able to fish the value out of `SchedLgU.txt` so I can be notified when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use an API call it can:

```
Private Declare Sub ExitProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal uExitCode As Long)
```

In your code, you can exit with a value, like `7`, for the example below:

```
Call ExitProcess(7)
```

Note that calling the above will immediately exit Access without any prompt or saving or anything. It should be the very last thing you do.